# Write blocks of code to file VBS

Tags: windows, vbscript, windows-scripting

I've been making a simple VBS script that makes a new .vbs file, writes code to that file, and then deletes itself. However, when it tries to write the code itself, it thinks that the code is part of the actual script or something, not the code to write to the file, giving me the error "Expected end of statement" on line 12. Whats wrong?

```
Option Explicit
Dim fso, obj, nDirS, wshshell, oFile
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set obj = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
Const WR = 2
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set oFile = fso.OpenTextFile (obj.SpecialFolders("Desktop")&"\finished.vbs",WR,true)
'&vbCrLf&_
oFile.Writeline "Option Explicit"
oFile.Writeline "Dim fso, obj, nDirS, wshshell"
oFile.Writeline "Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")"
oFile.Writeline "Set obj = CreateObject("wscript.shell")"
oFile.Writeline "WScript.Sleep(1000)"
oFile.Writeline "CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Popup "Error in Memory 16x", 5, "Oops""
```

Answer (score 0):

Your quotes are not escaped. Use "" to print a quote within a string, otherwise it will think your string ended and start interpreting the code following it instead.

```
Option Explicit
Dim fso, obj, nDirS, wshshell, oFile
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set obj = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
Const WR = 2
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set oFile = fso.OpenTextFile (obj.SpecialFolders("Desktop")&"\finished.vbs",WR,true)

oFile.Writeline "Option Explicit"
oFile.Writeline "Dim fso, obj, nDirS, wshshell"
oFile.Writeline "Set fso = CreateObject(""Scripting.FileSystemObject"")"
oFile.Writeline "Set obj = CreateObject(""wscript.shell"")"
oFile.Writeline "WScript.Sleep(1000)"
oFile.Writeline "CreateObject(""WScript.Shell"").Popup ""Error in Memory 16x"", 5, ""Oops"""
```